# Error Value of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection' cannot be converted to 'String'

Tags: sql, vb.net, error-handling

Cant seem to figure what code to use in this error.

It points on this line  Dim Flag_DR As SqlDataReader = Flag_com.ExecuteReader

Thanks a lot

```
            Private Sub txt_Password_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles txt_Password.KeyDown
            If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
            If txt_Username.Text = "hospital" And txt_Password.Text = "user" Then
            Me.Hide()

            Dim r0 As String

            Dim Flag_constr As New SqlConnection("Data Source=(localdb)\Projects;Initial Catalog=MasterDB;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False")
            'Dim Fill_Textbox_cmdstr As String = "select Regno,Name,Age,Address,Phone,Checkupdate,Checkuptime,Disease,Bloodgroup,Doctor,Remarks from clinicpatients where Regno=1"
            Dim Flag_cmdstr As String = "select * from flag"
            Dim Flag_con As New SqlConnection("Data Source=(localdb)\Projects;Initial Catalog=MasterDB;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False")
            Dim Flag_com As New SqlCommand(Flag_cmdstr, Flag_con)
            Flag_con.Open()
            Dim Flag_DR As SqlDataReader = Flag_com.ExecuteReader
            While Flag_DR.Read
                r0 = Flag_DR(0)
            End While
            Flag_con.Close()

            If r0 = 0 Then
                Dim objfrmBed As New frmBed()
                objfrmBed.Show()
            ElseIf r0 = 1 Then
                Dim objfrmMain As New frmMain()
                objfrmMain.Show()
            End If
```

Comment: you already created a connection with `Flag_constr` using an actual connection string, the second one `Flag_con` is redundant.  your repetitive variable names have you confused

Comment: Your edit has completely changed the question.  The error you list cannot possibly come from the line you say it does.  Plus it makes @Plutonix comment nonsensical.

Comment: whay is this question has -1 points?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is something wrong with your connection string. can you change this like below and try again:

```
Dim Flag_con As New SqlConnection("Data Source=(localdb)\Projects;Initial Catalog=MasterDB;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;")
```

Comment: i think this is right. what do you think? did it work?